# FCU: DeviceError:serial:open: No such file or directory

Tags: gazebo, ros-noetic, mavros, px4

I am try to simulate UAV in gazebo using `px4` and `mavros` `roslaunch mavros px4.launch`
got the following error

```
... logging to /home/mubashir/.ros/log/595548e6-bb3f-11ee-bab8-f3b849e8f78c/roslaunch-pc-8488.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take a while.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://pc:39963/

SUMMARY
========

CLEAR PARAMETERS
 * /mavros/

PARAMETERS
 * /mavros/camera/frame_id: base_link
 * /mavros/cmd/use_comp_id_system_control: False
 * /mavros/conn/heartbeat_rate: 1.0
 * /mavros/conn/system_time_rate: 1.0
 * /mavros/conn/timeout: 10.0
 * /mavros/conn/timesync_rate: 10.0
 * /mavros/distance_sensor/hrlv_ez4_pub/field_of_view: 0.0
 * /mavros/distance_sensor/hrlv_ez4_pub/frame_id: hrlv_ez4_sonar
 * /mavros/distance_sensor/hrlv_ez4_pub/id: 0
 * /mavros/distance_sensor/hrlv_ez4_pub/orientation: PITCH_270
 * /mavros/distance_sensor/hrlv_ez4_pub/send_tf: True
 * /mavros/distance_sensor/hrlv_ez4_pub/sensor_position/x: 0.0
 * /mavros/distance_sensor/hrlv_ez4_pub/sensor_position/y: 0.0
 * /mavros/distance_sensor/hrlv_ez4_pub/sensor_position/z: -0.1
 * /mavros/distance_sensor/laser_1_sub/id: 3
 * /mavros/distance_sensor/laser_1_sub/orientation: PITCH_270
 * /mavros/distance_sensor/laser_1_sub/subscriber: True
 * /mavros/distance_sensor/lidarlite_pub/field_of_view: 0.0
 * /mavros/distance_sensor/lidarlite_pub/frame_id: lidarlite_laser
 * /mavros/distance_sensor/lidarlite_pub/id: 1
 * /mavros/distance_sensor/lidarlite_pub/orientation: PITCH_270
 * /mavros/distance_sensor/lidarlite_pub/send_tf: True
 * /mavros/distance_sensor/lidarlite_pub/sensor_position/x: 0.0
 * /mavros/distance_sensor/lidarlite_pub/sensor_position/y: 0.0
 * /mavros/distance_sensor/lidarlite_pub/sensor_position/z: -0.1
 * /mavros/distance_sensor/sonar_1_sub/horizontal_fov_ratio: 1.0
 * /mavros/distance_sensor/sonar_1_sub/id: 2
 * /mavros/distance_sensor/sonar_1_sub/orientation: PITCH_270
 * /mavros/distance_sensor/sonar_1_sub/subscriber: True
 * /mavros/distance_sensor/sonar_1_sub/vertical_fov_ratio: 1.0
 * /mavros/fake_gps/eph: 2.0
 * /mavros/fake_gps/epv: 2.0
 * /mavros/fake_gps/fix_type: 3
 * /mavros/fake_gps/geo_origin/alt: 408.0
 * /mavros/fake_gps/geo_origin/lat: 47.3667
 * /mavros/fake_gps/geo_origin/lon: 8.55
 * /mavros/fake_gps/gps_rate: 5.0
 * /mavros/fake_gps/mocap_transform: True
 * /mavros/fake_gps/satellites_visible: 5
 * /mavros/fake_gps/tf/child_frame_id: fix
 * /mavros/fake_gps/tf/frame_id: map
 * /mavros/fake_gps/tf/listen: False
 * /mavros/fake_gps/tf/rate_limit: 10.0
 * /mavros/fake_gps/tf/send: False
 * /mavros/fake_gps/use_mocap: True
 * /mavros/fake_gps/use_vision: False
 * /mavros/fcu_protocol: v2.0
 * /mavros/fcu_url: /dev/ttyACM0:57600
 * /mavros/gcs_url: 
 * /mavros/global_position/child_frame_id: base_link
 * /mavros/global_position/frame_id: map
 * /mavros/global_position/gps_uere: 1.0
 * /mavros/global_position/rot_covariance: 99999.0
 * /mavros/global_position/tf/child_frame_id: base_link
 * /mavros/global_position/tf/frame_id: map
 * /mavros/global_position/tf/global_frame_id: earth
 * /mavros/global_position/tf/send: False
 * /mavros/global_position/use_relative_alt: True
 * /mavros/image/frame_id: px4flow
 * /mavros/imu/angular_velocity_stdev: 0.0003490659 // 0...
 * /mavros/imu/frame_id: base_link
 * /mavros/imu/linear_acceleration_stdev: 0.0003
 * /mavros/imu/magnetic_stdev: 0.0
 * /mavros/imu/orientation_stdev: 1.0
 * /mavros/landing_target/camera/fov_x: 2.0071286398
 * /mavros/landing_target/camera/fov_y: 2.0071286398
 * /mavros/landing_target/image/height: 480
 * /mavros/landing_target/image/width: 640
 * /mavros/landing_target/land_target_type: VISION_FIDUCIAL
 * /mavros/landing_target/listen_lt: False
 * /mavros/landing_target/mav_frame: LOCAL_NED
 * /mavros/landing_target/target_size/x: 0.3
 * /mavros/landing_target/target_size/y: 0.3
 * /mavros/landing_target/tf/child_frame_id: camera_center
 * /mavros/landing_target/tf/frame_id: landing_target
 * /mavros/landing_target/tf/listen: False
 * /mavros/landing_target/tf/rate_limit: 10.0
 * /mavros/landing_target/tf/send: True
 * /mavros/local_position/frame_id: map
 * /mavros/local_position/tf/child_frame_id: base_link
 * /mavros/local_position/tf/frame_id: map
 * /mavros/local_position/tf/send: False
 * /mavros/local_position/tf/send_fcu: False
 * /mavros/mission/pull_after_gcs: True
 * /mavros/mission/use_mission_item_int: True
 * /mavros/mocap/use_pose: True
 * /mavros/mocap/use_tf: False
 * /mavros/mount/debounce_s: 4.0
 * /mavros/mount/err_threshold_deg: 10.0
 * /mavros/mount/negate_measured_pitch: False
 * /mavros/mount/negate_measured_roll: False
 * /mavros/mount/negate_measured_yaw: False
 * /mavros/odometry/fcu/odom_child_id_des: base_link
 * /mavros/odometry/fcu/odom_parent_id_des: map
 * /mavros/plugin_blacklist: ['safety_area', '...
 * /mavros/plugin_whitelist: []
 * /mavros/px4flow/frame_id: px4flow
 * /mavros/px4flow/ranger_fov: 0.118682
 * /mavros/px4flow/ranger_max_range: 5.0
 * /mavros/px4flow/ranger_min_range: 0.3
 * /mavros/safety_area/p1/x: 1.0
 * /mavros/safety_area/p1/y: 1.0
 * /mavros/safety_area/p1/z: 1.0
 * /mavros/safety_area/p2/x: -1.0
 * /mavros/safety_area/p2/y: -1.0
 * /mavros/safety_area/p2/z: -1.0
 * /mavros/setpoint_accel/send_force: False
 * /mavros/setpoint_attitude/reverse_thrust: False
 * /mavros/setpoint_attitude/tf/child_frame_id: target_attitude
 * /mavros/setpoint_attitude/tf/frame_id: map
 * /mavros/setpoint_attitude/tf/listen: False
 * /mavros/setpoint_attitude/tf/rate_limit: 50.0
 * /mavros/setpoint_attitude/use_quaternion: False
 * /mavros/setpoint_position/mav_frame: LOCAL_NED
 * /mavros/setpoint_position/tf/child_frame_id: target_position
 * /mavros/setpoint_position/tf/frame_id: map
 * /mavros/setpoint_position/tf/listen: False
 * /mavros/setpoint_position/tf/rate_limit: 50.0
 * /mavros/setpoint_raw/thrust_scaling: 1.0
 * /mavros/setpoint_velocity/mav_frame: LOCAL_NED
 * /mavros/startup_px4_usb_quirk: False
 * /mavros/sys/disable_diag: False
 * /mavros/sys/min_voltage: 10.0
 * /mavros/target_component_id: 1
 * /mavros/target_system_id: 1
 * /mavros/tdr_radio/low_rssi: 40
 * /mavros/time/time_ref_source: fcu
 * /mavros/time/timesync_avg_alpha: 0.6
 * /mavros/time/timesync_mode: MAVLINK
 * /mavros/vibration/frame_id: base_link
 * /mavros/vision_pose/tf/child_frame_id: vision_estimate
 * /mavros/vision_pose/tf/frame_id: odom
 * /mavros/vision_pose/tf/listen: False
 * /mavros/vision_pose/tf/rate_limit: 10.0
 * /mavros/vision_speed/listen_twist: True
 * /mavros/vision_speed/twist_cov: True
 * /mavros/wheel_odometry/child_frame_id: base_link
 * /mavros/wheel_odometry/count: 2
 * /mavros/wheel_odometry/frame_id: odom
 * /mavros/wheel_odometry/send_raw: True
 * /mavros/wheel_odometry/send_twist: False
 * /mavros/wheel_odometry/tf/child_frame_id: base_link
 * /mavros/wheel_odometry/tf/frame_id: odom
 * /mavros/wheel_odometry/tf/send: False
 * /mavros/wheel_odometry/use_rpm: False
 * /mavros/wheel_odometry/vel_error: 0.1
 * /mavros/wheel_odometry/wheel0/radius: 0.05
 * /mavros/wheel_odometry/wheel0/x: 0.0
 * /mavros/wheel_odometry/wheel0/y: -0.15
 * /mavros/wheel_odometry/wheel1/radius: 0.05
 * /mavros/wheel_odometry/wheel1/x: 0.0
 * /mavros/wheel_odometry/wheel1/y: 0.15
 * /rosdistro: noetic
 * /rosversion: 1.16.0

NODES
  /
    mavros (mavros/mavros_node)

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [8503]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to 595548e6-bb3f-11ee-bab8-f3b849e8f78c
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [8520]
started core service [/rosout]
process[mavros-2]: started with pid [8528]
[ INFO] [1706159125.586876777]: FCU URL: /dev/ttyACM0:57600
[ INFO] [1706159125.588129257]: serial0: device: /dev/ttyACM0 @ 57600 bps
[FATAL] [1706159125.588247399]: FCU: DeviceError:serial:open: No such file or directory
================================================================================REQUIRED process [mavros-2] has died!
process has finished cleanly
log file: /home/mubashir/.ros/log/595548e6-bb3f-11ee-bab8-f3b849e8f78c/mavros-2*.log
Initiating shutdown!
================================================================================
[mavros-2] killing on exit
[rosout-1] killing on exit
[master] killing on exit
shutting down processing monitor...
... shutting down processing monitor complete
done
```

I am using ros noetic with gazebo11

Comment: Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange! Please make sure the device is connected. What does `ls /dev/ttyACM0` command say?

Comment: Thank you. following command `ls /dev/` show me following `/dev/tty`, I think I do not need a device connected at `/dev' I want to do gazebo similation sitl

Comment: You should be checking `ls /dev/ttyACM0` instead. On the other hand, please check the documentation carefully. Currently, your command `roslaunch mavros px4.launch` is looking for a device connected at `/dev/ttyACM0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem solves by giving the following argument `fcu_url:="udp://:14540@127.0.0.1:14557` just make sure dependant packages are installed and run `roslaunch mavros px4.launch fcu_url:="udp://:14540@127.0.0.1:14557"`. so by default the is `/dev/ttyACM0` which mean the launch file expect an `flight controller` is connected to it. but we are taking the data from the simulation, not the physical hardware.